# Position of "than"

Tags: comparatives, comparisons

Which of the following sentence structures is correct, or sounds better?

> 1. They grow at a faster rate up to three years after treatment **than** comparable plants.
> 2. They grow at a faster rate **than** comparable plants up to three years after treatment.

Thanks.

Comment: The second one is clearly preferable, but neither one is particularly clear. I think you are missing a *for*.

Comment: Thanks very much. Do you mean it should read "for up to three years"?

Comment: In addition to putting "for" between "plants" and "up", I think the second sentence should have "other" between "than" and "comparable" so the whole sentence would be "They grow at a faster rate than other comparable plants for up to three years after treatment."

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that is what @RegDwighт means: "**for** up to three years"

Comment: @axrwkr Why? I disagree. *Other* is obvious and implied. *Comparable plants* **must** exclude the plants in question. If anything, including *other* could introduce ambiguity. *They grow at a faster rate than **other** comparable plants* prompts the question, "Which other comparable plants?" - **some** other comparable plants?; **all** other comparable plants?

Comment: @TrevorD the ambiguity is still there with or without **other** since it is obvious and implied. I think that if you decided not to include **for** then you should include **other** "They grow at a faster rate than other comparable plants up to three years after treatment." without **for** or **other**, to me, something just seems to be missing

Comment: You need *for* before *up* in each case.

Comment: @axrwkr I agree with Andrew that *for* in necessary in any case. Including *for* is completely independent of including *other*. The two issues are **not** linked. You have agreed that *other* is obvious and implied - so why make a special point of saying "the second sentence **should have** *other*" (emphasis added). It's debatable whether the ambiguity is there with or without *other*, but IMHO adding *other* **increases** any ambiguity. Without *other*, I would understand the meaning as ***all** comparable plants*.

Comment: 10 litres of conditions in a five-litre container. Use two or more sentences. Boundary conditions are important and should be spelled out clearly, even if redundantly.

Answer (score 1):

The second is the closest, but to be perfectly clear, add the word "for":

They grow at a faster rate than comparable plants for up to three years after treatment.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct, though the second is preferred stylistically. The general principle is that long, or "heavy" adjuncts should be placed at either the beginning or end of a sentence where possible. This aids comprehension. Shifting of heavy constituents is also useful in the case of relative clauses, which can be quite long. Consider (relative clauses bracketed):

1. What man [who can look on her beauty and not feel remorse for the way she was treated] is there?
2. What man is there [who can look on her beauty and not feel remorse for the way she was treated]?

Both are "grammatically correct," but most would agree that the "extraposed" relative clause (#2) is to be preferred from a comprehensibility standpoint, because it does not make you wait forever to hear the predicate, even though the relative clause is separated from the noun it modifies (*man*).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the proposal by @Cyberherbalist, but I would also suggest that the first version could additionally be clarified by adding the little word "do":

> They grow at a faster rate *for* up to three years after treatment than *do* comparable plants.

Answer (score -3):

The first would be preferred since the second statement will apply the "up to three years after treatment" to comparable plants than to the former.